# bash: sed: unexpected behavior: displays everything

Tags: bash, sed

I wrote what I thought was a quick script I could run on a bunch of machines. Instead it print what looks like might be directory contents in a recursive search:

```
version=$(mysql Varnish -B --skip-column-names -e "SELECT value FROM sys_param WHERE param='PatchLevel'" | sed -n 's/^.*\([0-9]\.[0-9]*\).*$/\1/p')
if [[ $(echo "if($version == 6.10) { print 1; } else { print 0; }" | bc) -eq 1 ]]; then
    status=$(dpkg-query -l | awk '{print $2}' |  grep 'sg-status-polling');
    cons=$(dpkg-query -l | awk '{print $2}' |  grep 'sg-consolidated-poller');
    if [[ "$status" != "" && "$cons" != "" ]]; then
        echo "about to change /var/www/Varnish/lib/Extra/SG/ObjectPoller2.pm"; echo;
        cp /var/www/Varnish/lib/Extra/SG/ObjectPoller2.pm /var/www/Varnish/lib/Extra/SG/ObjectPoller2.pm.bkup;
        sed -ir '184s!\x91\x93!\x91\x27--timeout=35\x27\x93!'  /var/www/Varnish/lib/Extra/SG/ObjectPoller2.pm;
        sed -n 183,185p /var/www/Varnish/lib/Extra/SG/ObjectPoller2.pm; echo;
    else
        echo "packages not found. Assumed to be not applicable";
    fi
else
    echo "This is 4.$version, skipping";
fi
```

The script is supposed to make sure Varnish is version 4.6.10 and has 2 custom .deb packages installed (not through apt-get). then makes a backup and edits a single line in a perl module from `[]` to `['--timeout=35']`

it looks like its tripping up on the sed replace one liner.

Comment: Your script has a large number of external dependencies. Please try to reduce it to a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: Also, the first `if` condition is hopelessly overcomplicated, and monkey-patching system Perl code seems extremely miadirected.

Comment: Does the `if` intend to say `if [ $version == 6.10 ]; then ...; else ...; fi`? I also suggest using `grep -q` to test for the presence of your packages (if there isn't a more proper way).

Comment: Are you sure `\x91\x93` is what you need? This seems to miss my square brackets. Using `sed -ri'.bkup' 's!\[\]!\[\x27--timeout=35\x27\]!' foo` seems to work for me though...

Comment: so... no one has ever seen an sed command print out random garbage, so I must be crazy then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major problems (minor ones addressed in comments). The first is that you use the *decimal* code for `[]` instead of the hexa, so you should use `\x5b\x5d` instead of `\x91\x93`. The second problem is that if you *do* use the proper codes, `sed` will still interpret those syntactically as `[]`. So you can't escape escaping. Here's what you should call:

```
sed -ri'.bkup' '184s!\[\]![\x27--timeout=35\x27]!' /var/www/Varnish/lib/Extra/SG/ObjectPoller2.pm
```

And this will create the backup for you (but you should double check).